# SITE CHMOD command failed through ftp, can't figure out why

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftp-client

Using FTPClient for .NET 2.0.

I'm connecting to a vsftpd server and I'm able to write the file, but I'm unable to run the command. I've supplied the code below.

I'm also able to run QUOTE SITE chmod commands when I use a command prompt to login to the ftp server. I got a 200 SITE CHMOD command ok.

Is this a configuraton setting on the server?

```
        ftpClient.Connect();
        string ftpLoc = folder + fileName;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile))
        using (Stream ostream = ftpClient.OpenWrite(ftpLoc))
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ostream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                FtpReply reply;
                if (!(reply = ftpClient.Execute("SITE chmod 775 " + fileName)).Success)
                {
                    throw new FtpCommandException(reply);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logSW.WriteLine("ftp error: " + e.InnerException + " | " + e.Message);
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what was the code you used to change the working directory?

Answer (score 0):

It might depend how you login.

From the VSFTPD [configuration manpage](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html)

chmod_enable

When enabled, allows use of the SITE CHMOD command. **NOTE! This only applies to local users. Anonymous users never get to use SITE CHMOD.**

```
Default: YES
```

Comment: Thanks. My ftp skills are non-existent. I can browse to where the conf folder, but I can't figure out the command to open the file. I tried vi, and I tried typing in the conf file name to no avail.

Comment: You should be able to do a "more <filename>" or "cat <filename>".

Comment: Fixed it. If anyone else runs across this issue, I was not in the correct directory. I was able to write to a folder that I wasn't currently in, but I was unable to change permission on a file in a folder I wasn't it. So I just changed the working directory and it worked.